# Excluding patients based on future event; predictive model

Tags: predictive-models

I often see studies where predictive models are made with exclusion criteria such as “excluded patients with length of stay greater than 30 days”.

The model is then fit on the cohort without these patients.

This seems odd to me because it is not known at prediction which patients will have a stay over 30 days and which won’t.  If these patients were excluded, the model doesn’t apply to them (they had no “say” over the estimations”), but it’s impossible to tell whether the patient for which we need a prediction is in this group or not.  The model then actually applies to no patients.

Is there a formal term for this practice (error)?

Comment: A term common in finance is lookahead bias. A related term is survivorship bias.

Comment: Thank you, glad to see that it’s a recognized problem!  I wonder why it is so common

Comment: Don't the studies you "often see" analyze based on data available at the time of hospital discharge?  I.e., when length of stay is in fact known.

Comment: I will try to find some examples and update the question